# The cost of optional in Swift

Tags: swift, performance, option-type

I want to know if there is any performance cost associated with optionals in Swift e.g if we had to work with optionals repeatedly. Consider the following two code snippets
First approach

```
    var f: Foo?
    // foo returns an optional
    if let anotherF = foo() {
        f = anotherF
    }
    else {
        f = Foo()
    }
    f?.doSomething()
    f?.doSomethingElse()
    f?.doAnotherThing()
    // and so on
```

Second approach

```
    var f = Foo()
    if let anotherF = foo() {
        f = anotherF
    }
    f.doSomething()
    f.doAnotherThing()
    f.doAnotherThing()
    // and so on
```

Is there any performance benefit of second approach as compared with first one

Comment: You don't need to declare f as an optional in the first example, the Swift compiler can figure out that f will be defined in all possible code paths.

Comment: Why use an optional (or `var`) at all? Just do: `let f = foo() ?? Foo()`.

Comment: In the scenario I am working on we must check `foo()` before creating a new instance. It is declared as 
```func foo() -> Foo?```

Comment: Thats what the line from maddy does. Its called the nil coalescing operator. So it tries to assign f to foo() and if that doesn't work (??) it creates a new instance.

Comment: For value types, in the general case, and optional is just a wrapper that tacks on a `isPresent` boolean byte, in addition to the payload. Conditional binding is a matter of just checking that bool. For enums and objects (instances of classes), the `nil` case can be represented by an extra inhabitant. E.g. for object references, `nil` is modelled by a reference of `0x0000_0000`. https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/docs/ABIStabilityManifesto.md#data-layout

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This:

```
func bar(foo: Foo) {
    foo.doSomething()
}
```

generates the following assembly:

```
bar`bar(foo:):
0x100001370 <+0>:  pushq  %rbp
0x100001371 <+1>:  movq   %rsp, %rbp
0x100001374 <+4>:  pushq  %r13
0x100001376 <+6>:  subq   $0x18, %rsp
0x10000137a <+10>: movq   %rdi, -0x10(%rbp)
0x10000137e <+14>: movq   (%rdi), %rax
0x100001381 <+17>: movq   0x50(%rax), %rax
0x100001385 <+21>: movq   %rdi, %r13
0x100001388 <+24>: movq   %rdi, -0x18(%rbp)
0x10000138c <+28>: callq  *%rax
0x10000138e <+30>: movq   -0x18(%rbp), %rdi
0x100001392 <+34>: callq  0x1000013f0               ; swift_rt_swift_release
0x100001397 <+39>: addq   $0x18, %rsp
0x10000139b <+43>: popq   %r13
0x10000139d <+45>: popq   %rbp
0x10000139e <+46>: retq
```

However this:

```
func bar(foo: Foo?) {
    foo?.doSomething()
}
```

generates the following:

```
bar`bar(foo:):
0x100001340 <+0>:  pushq  %rbp
0x100001341 <+1>:  movq   %rsp, %rbp
0x100001344 <+4>:  pushq  %r13
0x100001346 <+6>:  subq   $0x18, %rsp
0x10000134a <+10>: movq   %rdi, -0x10(%rbp)
0x10000134e <+14>: movq   %rdi, -0x18(%rbp)
0x100001352 <+18>: callq  0x1000013f0               ; swift_rt_swift_retain
0x100001357 <+23>: movq   -0x18(%rbp), %rdi
0x10000135b <+27>: cmpq   $0x0, %rdi
0x10000135f <+31>: sete   %al
0x100001362 <+34>: xorb   $-0x1, %al
0x100001364 <+36>: testb  $0x1, %al
0x100001366 <+38>: jne    0x100001373               ; <+51> at main.swift:16
0x100001368 <+40>: movq   -0x18(%rbp), %rdi
0x10000136c <+44>: callq  0x100001400               ; swift_rt_swift_release
0x100001371 <+49>: jmp    0x10000139a               ; <+90> at main.swift:16
0x100001373 <+51>: movq   -0x18(%rbp), %rax
0x100001377 <+55>: movq   (%rax), %rcx
0x10000137a <+58>: movq   %rax, %r13
0x10000137d <+61>: callq  *0x50(%rcx)
0x100001380 <+64>: movq   -0x18(%rbp), %rdi
0x100001384 <+68>: callq  0x100001400               ; swift_rt_swift_release
0x100001389 <+73>: movq   -0x18(%rbp), %rdi
0x10000138d <+77>: callq  0x100001400               ; swift_rt_swift_release
0x100001392 <+82>: addq   $0x18, %rsp
0x100001396 <+86>: popq   %r13
0x100001398 <+88>: popq   %rbp
0x100001399 <+89>: retq   
0x10000139a <+90>: jmp    0x100001389               ; <+73> at main.swift:17
```

As you can see, the optional version generates a few more instructions, so there would seem to be some overhead involved. My expectation is that it would be small, though.

Comment: Thats means if there is a tight loop and inside loop `f?.doSomething()` is called then there may comes a time overhead is more significant

Comment: @KhurramShehzad Yeah, it's better to unwrap and start the loop only once you have a non-optional reference.

Comment: @KhurramShehzad Each `foo?.doSomething` is yet another branch which must check whether the `Optional` is `nil` or `not`. Most often they can be optimized out, but this is just messy.